# Why can not instantiate an empty Angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface, npm-install

Why can not instantiate an empty Angular app?

I am following the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local.

I installed angular first with the command: `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Now I am trying to create an empty app by running the: `ng new app`.

Here is the output I am getting:

```
my.name@mylaptop MINGW64 ~/source/repos/parentFolder
$ ng new app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? SCSS   [ https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss                ]
CREATE app/angular.json (3657 bytes)
CREATE app/package.json (1289 bytes)
CREATE app/README.md (1021 bytes)
CREATE app/tsconfig.json (543 bytes)
CREATE app/tslint.json (1953 bytes)
CREATE app/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE app/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE app/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE app/karma.conf.js (1015 bytes)
CREATE app/tsconfig.app.json (270 bytes)
CREATE app/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE app/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE app/src/index.html (289 bytes)
CREATE app/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE app/src/polyfills.ts (2838 bytes)
CREATE app/src/styles.scss (80 bytes)
CREATE app/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE app/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)    
CREATE app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (246 bytes)      
CREATE app/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.html (25530 bytes)       
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1089 bytes)     
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.ts (208 bytes)
CREATE app/src/app/app.component.scss (0 bytes)
CREATE app/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE app/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE app/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (636 bytes)
CREATE app/e2e/src/app.po.ts (262 bytes)
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/node@~8.9.4.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting 
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'app'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\my.name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\dateandtime7Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Of course I can run the `npm i @types/node` and it works, it installs the `@types/node@~13` version for me. But that does not help me to create a project, because after running the `npm i @types/node` I still do not have an empty angular project.

Help me, please, with this stupid error. It drives me crazy, because it is supposed to be the easiest thing during development - empty project creation. But I stumbled at it seriously as if I have no brains whatever, because I can not do it.

My desired outcome is having an empty default angular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the latest node Js

   https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Run the below command on CLI

   ```
   ng new my-app
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the latest node Js

   https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Delete the *package-lock.json* file
3. Install the npm using the below command

   ```
   npm install
   ```

Comment: Neither of your answers help. The same error is popping up.